# Share mp3 file from Storage to specific whatsapp user

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

```
private void share(Uri uri){
    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("audio/*");
    waIntent.putExtra("jid", get_DATA.getSelectedPhonewdcountrycode() + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix

    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
}
```

I have tried many solution but every solutio takes me to whatsapp contact list to chose a contact, i want the file to be send directly to users inbox
BTW it does take me to the targeted contact after a few second delay but it toast a message File is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by asking user to select contact from list and then redirected to WhatsApp using intent (a short version now exist as `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919773207706&text=Hello`,
[Here  is the a use full link relevant to it](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?locale=en_US)
) **BUT** the main problem with my app was the **File is not supported** which was a security issue that was solved using MediScanner along with file provider configurations

Answer (score 0):

There is no foreseeable way to upload it directly from a file to a user (unlike on laptops), unless you extend the file path to reach a particular contact e.g

`com.whatsapp.jeremy`

This however might still not help as WhatsApp chats are end to end encrypted, not direct, so you might have to go through some of the database files like `db.crypt` to find the right path to each individual.
Try seeing how these pan out for you